# How to make a logo that is positioned at X&Y of a page and go down if there is a lot of content

Tags: html, css

For a lot of you this is easy but it's making me mad:

I have a webpage (black area) where div (red area) contains some content which I don't know how much is.

If the content is less then it needs to reach the logo, the logo should stay positionend in that point of my div, it shouldn't go up.

If the content is more, it shuld go down (keeping a fixed distance from text)

How to achieve this?

[image: Not a lot of content image]
[image: A lot of content image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [min-height](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/min-height) CSS property:

```
div { min-height:400px; }
```

http://jsbin.com/oxodak/2/

Comment: A great suggestion and a good example, but I finally used the other one

Comment: @Fire-Dragon-DoL the sticky footer hack has it uses, but I don't think it's necessary in this case. Lots of CSS, negative margins and an extraneous element instead of a simple, hack-free solution.

Comment: You are right, while I were tweaking (after accepted the answer) with it I encountered a big problem (hard to explain, my css is much more complex than what I proposed in the question, it has to do with margins. The article states that those can be a problem) and I solved by simply setting the min-height property, which allowed me to forget about everything else. I'm changing the answer to this one, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

You want a "sticky footer", but contained inside a `div` instead of the whole page.

Tweak the method shown here: http://ryanfait.com/resources/footer-stick-to-bottom-of-page/

Comment: Thanks a lot (you again saved me!) that method is working gracefully